# To which JS file the ajax request is forwarded to?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

`Example ajax('/abc/123',{blah,blah})`
I have the entire backend code...Just wanted to know where the ajax request would go and be processed.Really new to this,should this info be enough or I would need to put in more info...Please guide.

Comment: this make a get or post request to the server ;

Comment: Yes but to which file does the request go to and gets processed ?

Comment: you should have a route to handle such request . in nodejs it would look like `app.get('/abc/123', function(req , res) // handle request `

Comment: `ajax('/abc/123',{data: { login: this.get('xyz') },
        type: 'POST'
      }).then(success, fail).finally(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
          self.set('disabled',false);
        }, 500);
      });`
Is this what you are asking?

Comment: this is post request , it sends data to the server . 
the code that would process this request should look like 
`app.post('/abc/123' , function(req ,res){})` or 
`app.post('/abc/:id , function(req , res){}`;

Comment: Should it be under the javascript folder?Really sorry for not getting it clearly...

Comment: I don't know how the project structure is laid out , 
but if there is an app folder or a route folder , the file you are looking for should be there .

Comment: It is built on ruby on rails..and I can see both route and app folder

Comment: you are using rails . then there is a routes.rb file under config folder . 
there is your application routing configuration .

Comment: Is it okay to disclose the project name if it is open source and if it is a commercial application too?Thanks a lot for co-operating too....really appreciate it

Comment: its okay if project is an open source

Comment: Okay...wanted to know about how the password reset logic is done in the discourse forum project....if you could please let me know..thanks